# How can a template-driven form access a control inside a component?

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I have a `<form>` that uses the Template Driven approach.

The form contains a mix of native controls, like `<input>` and `<select>`, and also wrapper components, like `<text-control>` and `<checkbox-control>` that contains the native `<input>` element inside of it.

How can the form access the `<text-control>`'s native element to read its error and touched state?

Also, if I want to place a validator directive on that wrapper component and have it pipe-down to the native `<input>`, how can I approach this?

I tried to use `ngModel` on the wrapper component, but it doesn't work, since `ngModel` is hooking to the wrapper component, not the underlying `<input>` element.

Another approach was to use `<ng-content>`, but the underlying native element takes a lot of attributes, so much that it'll be a pain to copy-n-paste it everywhere.

Example:

```html
<checkbox-control>
  <!-- Now, it's easy for the form to access the control. -->
  <!-- But I've too many attributes and properties that go here. -->
  <input type="checkbox">
</checkbox-control>
```

*PS: I am not looking to use ElementRef to access the native element, I just want the `<form>` to be aware of the native elements' error state, so that I can tell whether the form is valid or not.*

Example:

```html
<form #editor="ngForm">
  <input type="text" validateText />

  <select validateSelect>
    <option value="1"></option>
    <option value="2"></option>
  </select>

  <!-- Does not work. -->
  <checkbox-control validateCheckbox></checkbox-control>
</form>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: I think a ControlValueAccessor might be what you’re looking for..?

Answer (score 0):

You can use element's local reference in template approach.
Please refer to this code I just wrote to explain :

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-7no9ok?file=src/app/app.component.html

Comment: I don't think this is what I was looking for. In your provided example, no use for wrapper components was introduced (i.e. `<text-control>` or `<checkbox-control>`).

Comment: I believe you want to check the validity of the native controls only? correct?

Answer (score 0):

I found a reasonable solution that works without writing much code, and without editing too many components.

**Step 1: Create your validator**

```
@Directive({ selector: '[assertNoSpecialChars]' })
export class SpecialCharacterValidator implements Validator {
  // The directive will have a reference for the name of the form's control.
  @Input() assertNoSpecialChars: string = '';

  validate(group: FormGroup): ValidationErrors | null {
    const control = group.controls[this.assertNoSpecialChars];

    // For simplicity, let's say we don't want the dollar sign in our input.
    if (control.value.includes('$')) {
      return { invalid: true };
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  }
}
```

**Step 2: Apply the directive on your form**

```html
<form #f="ngForm" [assertNoSpecialChars]="'username'">
  <text-control></text-control>
</form>
```

**Step 3: Bind the input event of your component to the hosting form component**

```html
<form #f="ngForm" [assertNoSpecialChars]="'username'">
  <text-control (input)="updateFormManually($event, 'username')"></text-control>
</form>
```

**Step 4: Get a reference for your NgForm, and implement the update mechanism**

```
@Component({})
export class FormComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  // Grab a reference for your NgForm.
  @ViewChild('f', { static: true }) f!: NgForm;

  // Create your form control.
  username: FormControl = new FormControl();

  // Register your control to the NgForm.
  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    this.f.form.addControl('username', this.username);
  }

  // Update the control manually.
  updateFormManually(event: any, controlName: string): void {
    this.f.form.controls[controlName].setValue(event.target.value);
  }
}
```

Now, the form's validity state, and error messages will be correctly bound.